# How to use attachInterrupt() in ATtiny85 with Arduino IDE?

Tags: interrupt, pins, attiny85

It's possible use external interrupts/attachInterrupt() with the ATtiny85 when I program with Arduino IDE?

If is possible, how many inputs (for external interrupts) the ATtiny85 have and which are they?
Someone have an example code?

Comment: The ATTINY 85 doesn't have external interrupts.  You'll have to use pin change interrupts instead.

Comment: Except... PB2 has INT0...

Comment: Darnit.  I just looked at the spec sheet and didn't see one listed.

Answer (score 2):

Pin PB2 is the only pin that has a real external interrupt.  This is `INT0`.

Whether you can use `attachInterrupt(0, ...)` or not is entirely down to whether it is implemented in the core that you are using.